# How to use pandas Grouper to get sum of values within each hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:

```
         Hora_Retiro  count_uses
0         00:00:18           1
1         00:00:34           1
2         00:02:27           1
3         00:03:13           1
4         00:06:45           1
...            ...         ...
748700    23:58:47           1
748701    23:58:49           1
748702    23:59:11           1
748703    23:59:47           1
748704    23:59:56           1
```

And I want to group all values within each hour, so I can see the total number of uses per hour (00:00:00 - 23:00:00)

I have the following code:

```
hora_pico_aug= hora_pico.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="Hora_Retiro",freq='H')).count()
```

Hora_Retiro column is of timedelta64[ns] type
Which gives the following output:

```
                count_uses
Hora_Retiro            
00:00:02           2566
01:00:02            602
02:00:02            295
03:00:02              5
04:00:02             10
05:00:02           4002
06:00:02          16075
07:00:02          39410
08:00:02          76272
09:00:02          56721
10:00:02          36036
11:00:02          32011
12:00:02          33725
13:00:02          41032
14:00:02          50747
15:00:02          50338
16:00:02          42347
17:00:02          54674
18:00:02          76056
19:00:02          57958
20:00:02          34286
21:00:02          22509
22:00:02          13894
23:00:02           7134
```

However, the index column starts at 00:00:02, and I want it to start at 00:00:00, and then go from one hour intervals. Something like this:

```
                count_uses
Hora_Retiro            
00:00:00           2565
01:00:00            603
02:00:00            295
03:00:00              5
04:00:00             10
05:00:00           4002
06:00:00          16075
07:00:00          39410
08:00:00          76272
09:00:00          56721
10:00:00          36036
11:00:00          32011
12:00:00          33725
13:00:00          41032
14:00:00          50747
15:00:00          50338
16:00:00          42347
17:00:00          54674
18:00:00          76056
19:00:00          57958
20:00:00          34286
21:00:00          22509
22:00:00          13894
23:00:00           7134
```

How can i make it to start at 00:00:00??

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I was not able to reproduce this issue with a sample of your data. Try updating your version of pandas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `hour` column from `Hora_Retiro` column.

```
df['hour'] = df['Hora_Retiro'].dt.hour
```

And then `groupby` on the basis of `hour`

```
gpby_df = df.groupby('hour')['count_uses'].sum().reset_index()
gpby_df['hour'] = pd.to_datetime(gpby_df['hour'], format='%H').dt.time
gpby_df.columns = ['Hora_Retiro', 'sum_count_uses']
gpby_df
```

gives

```
Hora_Retiro sum_count_uses
0   00:00:00    14
1   09:00:00    1
2   10:00:00    2
3   20:00:00    2
```

Comment: Hi!  Thank you so much! Just as a side comment, I dont know why but .dt.hour doesnt work for some reason. However, i used df["Hora_Retiro"].dt.components["hours"]. I think it is because of the data type. But the rest work as expected! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that *Hora_Retiro* column in your DataFrame is of
*Timedelta* type. It is not *datetime*, as in this case there
would be printed also the date part.

Indeed, your code creates groups starting at the minute / second
taken from the first row.

To group by "full hours":

- round each element in this column to *hour*,
- then group (just by this rounded value).

The code to do it is:

```
hora_pico.groupby(hora_pico.Hora_Retiro.apply(
    lambda tt: tt.round('H'))).count_uses.count()
```

However I advise you to make up your mind, what do you want to count:
rows or values in *count_uses* column.
In the second case replace *count* function with *sum*.